# Why do we need the "crossorigin" attribute when preloading font files?

Tags: html, fonts, cors, preload

To correctly preload font files, we're told we always need the `crossorigin` attribute applied to our `<link rel="preload" />` tags, e.g:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/comicsans.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Can anybody give me the true reason for this? All I can find are links in MDN that just dictate this requirement, without going into any detail as to why:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload#cors-enabled_fetches

> When preloading resources that are fetched with CORS enabled (e.g. fetch(), XMLHttpRequest or ***fonts***), special care needs to be taken to setting the crossorigin attribute on your  element. The attribute needs to be set to match the resource's CORS and credentials mode, **even when the fetch is not cross-origin**.

> As mentioned above, one interesting case where this applies is **font files**. *Because of various reasons*, **these have to be fetched using anonymous-mode CORS** (see Font fetching requirements).

It seems counterintuitive to my understanding of CORS, and why it's necessary. I'm sure there's a good reason for this, I just can't find it.

Before anybody just links to the same docs I'm talking about, see below:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-fetching-requirements

I'd really like an in depth answer from somebody who really knows *why* this is a requirement, and what it's purpose is, with some evidence (docs, etc) to back it up.

Comment: This also perplexes me. Crossorigin is said to be necessary when the font files are on another server/domain yet it's necessary for preloading self-hosted font files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The HTML attribute `crossorigin` defines how to handle crossorigin requests. Setting the `crossorigin` attribute (equivalent to `crossorigin="anonymous"`) will switch the request to a CORS request using the `same-origin` policy. It is required on the `rel="preload"` as font requests require `same-origin` policy.

The same-origin policy is required on almost all new resource types, such as `fetch()`, `<script type="module">` or fonts. It doesn't apply to legacy resource types (images, scripts, css, video, audio) because of backwards-compatibility issues. `<link rel="preload">` is a special case because it is a modern feature which needs to support legacy resource types, such as preloading an image.

> the ideal is, from now on, you *always* SOR by default when you
> introduce a new type of linking. It's just the right thing to do,
> because it lets us avoid having to care about a whole annoying class
> of security issues. [Source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/TT9D5-Zfnzw/m/UKMHYjVe3scJ)

This requirement was then added to the W3C draft for CSS fonts.

> For font loads, user agents must use the potentially CORS-enabled fetch method defined by the [FETCH] specification for URL's defined within @font-face rules. When fetching, user agents must use "Anonymous" mode, set the referrer source to the stylesheet's URL and set the origin to the URL of the containing document. [Source](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#same-origin-restriction)

I have also come across repeated comments that it was requested by the font foundries to prevent font piracy, but I cannot substantiate that with evidence.

Other related links:

- [Discussion on Mozilla (dated 2010-10-14)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604421)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin
- [RFC6454](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6454)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response / explanation! Very useful

Comment: Does this mean that servers must return CORS headers, even when the request is from the same origin? That doesn't make any sense, but seems to be the case with preloading fonts.

Comment: If the fonts are hosted on a different origin (like Google Fonts) they would need to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but not if they are on the same origin. The badly named `crossorigin` attribute is setting the CORS policy to `same-origin`.